# How to Append a List Key Value using Another List

Tags: python, json, list, loops, append

I've been trying to get this to work.
There are two different JSON lists that contain different keys.

list1

```
[
    {
        "name":"John",
        "measurement": "5.11"
    },
    {
        "name":"Kate",
        "measurement": "5.6"
    }
]
```

list2

```
[
    {
        "name":"John",
        "characteristics": {
            "height": [
            "6.0"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name":"Mike",
        "characteristics": {
            "height": [
            "5.10"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

code

```
for k in list2:
    if v['name'] in [key['name'] for key in list1:
        list1.append(k['measurement'])
```

The output I get is,

```
[{'name': 'John', 'characteristics': ['height': '6.0', 'age': 30}, '5.11']
```

Expected output

```
[{'name': 'John', 'characteristics': ['height': '5.11', 'age': 30}]
```

The loops go over the keys and if the `key['name']` are equals in both lists,
then it proceeds into happening that specific values from the given key.
The only problem is that it is not working correctly for me. I just want to replace that value from height in characteristics with the one in measurement.

[EDIT]:
I made changes to the json. It should be correct now. Basically, `height` is an array.

Comment: ```[key['name']]``` missing ```]```

Comment: The code you presented has syntax errors. One pointed out by @Sujay, other such as, in `list2`, a closing quote missing in "height" and you have an extra colon after its value (6.0 and 5.11). Even more, if those items should be in the `key: value` format, they should be a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: I fixed it. That was my mistake because I typed it instead of copying and pasting it.
As for the key, how can I fix that? I used this exact for loop with the if statement from another script. Although, that for loop was for finding if the key was `not in` the other list.

Comment: You can use a dictionary, as `"characteristics": {"height": "5.10", "age", 25}`, though personally I don't see the point of just having `height` and `age` in the main dictionary along with `name`.

Comment: I tried switching the if statement to list1.get('name') == list2.get('name')

Comment: I think you need first to make sure the structure of your input data is as desired (and makes sense for Python). This, before getting to the question as to why your manipulation doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: @MatBBastos The issue with this is that I am requesting a call from an API URL that returns it in JSON.

Comment: Then please provide an actual example of this data. Currently, the list of dictionaries you presented has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON you posted is invalid so I fixed it little bit. Following code should work:

```
list_1 = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "measurement": "5.11"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kate",
        "measurement": "5.6"
    }
]

list_2 = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "characteristics": {
            "height": "6.0",
            "age": 30
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Mike",
        "characteristics": {
            "height": "5.10",
            "age": 25
        }
    }
]



result = []
for list_1_item in list_1:
    single_obj = {}
    for list_2_item in list_2:
        if list_2_item['name'] == list_1_item['name']:
            single_obj['name'] = list_1_item['name']
            single_obj['characteristics'] = list_2_item['characteristics']
            result.append(single_obj)

print(result)
```

This gives us following result:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'characteristics': {'height': '6.0', 'age': 30}}]
```

Comment: When I use the loops you wrote down, it throws the error:
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: I guess you have different input? Just copy and paste what I provided. It works

Comment: Actually, list_1 for me I already append it to a list, `list1 = []` and the same goes for list2. I did that after getting the response then I loop through that so I could add it as a list. I don't know if that makes a difference compared to your code.

Comment: So, now I understand the difference between a dict and a list. I thought I was working with a list. The above json is actually a dict. So, how could I modify my if statement to make it work with a dict instead?